# One database & REST service for different apps/multi-tenant architecture

Tags: android, mysql, database, laravel, software-design

I think this type of question is already posted here. But I need some suggestions which are directly related to my problem.

I am developing a mobile app in Ionic 3 for school management( include chats, notifications,student-parent communication etc) with the above features.
Now I already created a build for a single school and published in the app store. I have a REST API written in Laravel (data handling) and Nodejs (chat and real-time data) later hosted in AWS former hosted in shared hosting.

Consider when a new school comes, what should I do? Is it good practice to create a new database for that school? Assume almost all our school database have same MySQL schema. So need to replicate the schema for every school.
Is that is the good practice? Or how things are actually going in practical case?

I have heard the multi-tenant architecture. Is that is the way I proceed?

I have another doubt that if I choose different DB for every app. Then is it needed to create REST API for all DB?

Is it anyway to use the same rest API for different db/in my case different school. I have only a little experience in this. That's why I asking.

Comment: Why don't you add a new table `schools` and so a relationship between `users` and `schools` within the same DB.

Comment: @ako That is a valid approach, although this solution can come with a lot of work if the application exists already. You'd also need to make all other contents depend on one school to achieve actual segregation. I would look into https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant together with database schemas as segregation instead of whole databases. It doesn't really matter at this point though, as it is only a database connection setting...

Comment: Actually I have created REST service which have database connection to this current database only. If I created a new DB is it necessary to create new REST api clone. Totally confused how to handle this.

Comment: No there is no need to create new whole API, You must change the connection to the DB based on a specific param for example in the API request.

Comment: Let me clear one thing if it is school A : then api request eg: /SchoolA/api/etc.. and /schoolb/api/etc.. make db connection based on the route parameter. Isn't it

Comment: (shameless plug) here's example of multi-tenancy with table prefix: https://github.com/niiknow/laratt-api